# Run Junit Tests in Eclipse with Enhanced JDO Model Classes

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit, jdo

I want to to change my build tool from ant to gradle for an old dynamic web project(java).

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply from: 'gradle/enhance.gradle'

// JDK Version 
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

// version of the gradle wrapper
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // include local dependencies without a repo
    compile fileTree(dir: "${webAppDirName}/WEB-INF/lib", include: '*.jar')

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'

    //other dependencies ....

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'  
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

//Gretty Servlet Plugin for Embedded Tomcat
gretty {
  port = 8080
  contextPath = '/'
  servletContainer = 'tomcat7'

  // enalbe hot code replacement
  managedClassReload = true
}
```

I use the gretty plugin so I can run and deploy the project in a Tomcat with the `appRun` gradle task. All Entity Classes must be enhanced as I use JDO. Therefore I have the following gradle task, which is referenced in the global build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
    enhance

    testEnhance {
        extendsFrom enhance
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    enhance group: 'org.datanucleus', name: 'datanucleus-core', version: '4.1.8'
    //some more dependencies ...

    enhance group: 'log4j', name:'log4j', version: '1.2.16'

    enhance files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)

    testEnhance files(sourceSets.test.output.classesDir)    
}

ext.enhancerLog = "$projectDir/eclipse-config/DataNucleuslog4j.properties"

ext.enhanceTaskCount = 0

/**
 * Generates a non-conflicting task name (enhance may run more than once in a single execution phase).
 */
def antTaskDef(def classPath) {

    def taskName = 'datanucleusenhancer' + (project.ext.enhanceTaskCount++)

    // define Ant task for DataNucleus Enhancer
    ant.taskdef(
        name: taskName,
        classname: 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerTask',
        classpath: classPath
    )

    taskName
}

/**
 * Runs the task that enhances the JDO model classes.
 */
def runAntTask(String taskName, def classPath, def entityFiles) {

    ant."$taskName"(verbose: true, classpath: classPath, failonerror: true, api: "JDO") {

        entityFiles.addToAntBuilder(ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet)

        logger.info "Log properties file used: $enhancerLog"
        arg(value: "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$enhancerLog")
    }
}

/**
 * Runs the DataNucleus Enhancer task on the model classes after the compilation of the Java sources.
 */
task datanucleusEnhance {
    dependsOn compileJava

    description = "Enhance JPA model classes using DataNucleus Enhancer"
    group = "MyProject"

    doLast {
        // define the entity classes
        def entityFiles = fileTree(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir).matching {
            include '**/model/*.class'
        }

        logger.info 'Enhancing DataNucleus classes...'

        def classpath = project.configurations.enhance.asPath

        // define Ant task for DataNucleus Enhancer
        def taskName = antTaskDef(classpath)

        // run the DataNucleus Enhancer as an Ant task
        runAntTask(taskName, classpath, entityFiles)

        logger.info 'Enhancing done.'
    }
}

/**
 * Runs the DataNucleus Enhancer task on the model classes after the compilation of the test Java sources.
 */
task testDatanucleusEnhance {
    dependsOn compileTestJava

    description = "Enhance JPA model classes using DataNucleus Enhancer for Tests"
    group = "MyProject-Test"

    doLast {

        // define the entity classes
        def entityFiles = fileTree(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir).matching {
            include '**/model/*.class'
        }

        sourceSets.all {
            logger.info 'Enhancing sourceset ' + name

            if (output != null && output.classesDir != null && name != 'main') {

                logger.debug ' -> classes dir ' + output.classesDir

                entityFiles += fileTree(output.classesDir).matching {
                    include '**/model/*.class'
                    exclude '**/model/*Test*.class'
                    exclude '**/model/*Builder.class'
                }
            } else {
                logger.info ' -> no classes found!'
            }
        }

        logger.info 'Test - Enhancing DataNucleus classes...'

        def classpath = project.configurations.testEnhance.asPath

        // define Ant task for DataNucleus Enhancer
        def taskName = antTaskDef(classpath)

        // run the DataNucleus Enhancer as an Ant task
        runAntTask(taskName, classpath, entityFiles)

        logger.info 'Test - Enhancing done.'
    }
}

// the output of classes and testClasses should always be enhanced
tasks['classes'].dependsOn tasks['datanucleusEnhance']
tasks['testClasses'].dependsOn tasks['testDatanucleusEnhance']
```

When I call the gradle task `test` the tests are executed successfully. But when I run the test in eclipse (Neon 4.6) with Run As -> Junit Test all test fail because the Entity classes are not enhanced. I believe this is a configuration problem. The datanucleusEnhance gradle task puts the enhanced classes to `build/classes/main` and testDatanucleusEnhance `build/classes/test`. Does Eclipse maybe take the unenhanced classes from the `bin` directory and runs the Junit tests with them? What would be a solution?

Comment: have you tried to overwrite the unenhanced classes? rather than specifying a new location

Comment: yes I change the gradle output folder to the bin dir, same result as before. Its would not be a good solution anyway, cause this might cause problems between gradle and eclipse.